# How to provide a router navigate function in Angular 2 project

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

In my Angular 2 project I have a custom function `goToObject(objectType:string, objectID: number)` that I use to navigate to different objects throughout a couple of different components in my application. The function looks as follows:

```
goToObject(objectType:string, objectID: number) {
     this._router.navigate([type, id]);
}
```

I was wondering if there is a way to provide this function throughout my complete project, without having to define it in each component separately. What makes it harder I guess is that this function needs to use a instance of a router object. Would I have to try to provide it in my base component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a shared service

```
@Injectable() 
export class RouteServices {
  constructor(private _router:Router) {}
  navigate(...) {
     this._router.navigate([type, id]);
  }
}
```

then provide it at the root component and inject it where you want to use it and call its methods.

Comment: The injecting would have to happen in the constructor of each component where I use it, or not?