# unable to navigate the the required url in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular2-routing, angular2-services

i created paths and those paths working fine,in that i want to navigate the detail page.
ex:if user enters in id, click on button and it should navigate to detail page of the id.

have the component like this,

```
export class ComplaintStatusComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _complaintService:ComplaintService,private router:Router) { }

  complaints={};

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCompliants();
  }
  getComplaintDetails(complntId){


    this._complaintService.getCompliants(complntId).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
     this.router.navigate(['/complaintstatus', this.complntId]);
 }
 getCompliants():void{

 }
}
```

and service is:

```
export class ComplaintService{
    private _url:string ="http://192.168.1.58:8000/app/complaint/complaintstatus"
    constructor(private _http:Http){}
    getCompliants(complntId){
        return this._http.get(this._url + '/' + complntId).map((response:Response)=>response.json());

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to provide a router navigate function in Angular 2 project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37773529/how-to-provide-a-router-navigate-function-in-angular-2-project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 getComplaintDetails(complntId){


    this._complaintService.getCompliants(complntId).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
     this.router.navigate(['/complaintstatus', complntId]);
 }
```

remove the this before your id